# angular js load external site in iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe, external-url

I have one angular js application which is running on nodejs. I want to load an external site, the external site is also my application which is running on different IP, with-in a div while loading the template url. So in template url I mentioned one HTML file. Inside that HTML file I had written like this.

```
<iframe src="myexternalurl"></iframe>
```

But in error console it is coming like:

```
Refused to display 'myexternalurl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `x-frame-options` header to `ALLOW-FROM {your app domain}`

Apparently on your other application's host/server/app the header `x-frame-options` set to `SAMEORIGIN` you need to disable that header or correct it according to the `x-frame-options` possible values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add following line to `.htaccess` in your external site (If its your application)

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

If you want to allow some specific site. refer the below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: assumes that OP uses apache/.htaccess