# How to set X-Frame-Options header in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, zap

I'm getting an OWASP ZAP Scanning alert:

```
Medium (Medium)    X-Frame-Options Header Not Set
Description        X-Frame-Options header is not included in the HTTP response to protect against 'ClickJacking' attacks.
URL                https://10.11.12.13/web/network/config.html
Method             GET
Parameter          X-Frame-Options
```

To fix the alert I [set HTTP headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers) in *app.js*

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['X-Frame-Options'] = 'DENY';
```

When building a project I get a TypeError

```
[INFO]  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['X-Frame-Options']='DENY'')
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a different way of fixing the alert?

Comment: Yes, don't do this kind of stuff inside angular. Do it on the webserver or in a .htaccess file or a web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow the syntax in the article you [linked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers), which lists:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }
```

So yours should be something like :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'X-Frame-Options' : 'DENY' }
```

As MrWook suggested that might not be the best option. You should also checkout these answers:

- [How do I set X-Frame-Options as response header in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267011/how-do-i-set-x-frame-options-as-response-header-in-angularjs?rq=1)
- [angular js load external site in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046482/angular-js-load-external-site-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

`$httpProvider.defaults` is used to set **request** headers. Leaving aside your error in how you are trying to use it, `X-Frame-Options` is a **response** header.

You can't set response headers in Angular: It is a client-side application.

You need to configure your HTTP server (`https://10.11.12.13`) to include the header.

How you do that depends on which HTTP server software you use. [This guide](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/security-guides/how-to-configure-security-headers-in-nginx-and-apache), for example, covers Apache HTTPD and Nginx. You'll need to find documentation for the software you are using.